# Hibernate - How to map an primary key as composite-key of three objects

Tags: hibernate, mapping

I am trying to map an object. It has a primary key as composite-key of three Ids but they are in three distinct object: Role, SecApplication, SecFunction. I have searched information about how mapping from objects but I have found nothing about this. If it help with anything I put the code that I am trying:

```
<composite-key>
        <key-many-to-one name="role" class="Role.id" >
            <column name="id_perfil"/>
        </key-many-to-one>
        <key-many-to-one name="secApplication" class="SecApplication.id">
            <column name="id_aplicacion"/>
        </key-many-to-one>
        <key-many-to-one name="secFunction" class="SecFunction.id">
            <column name="id_funcion"/>
        </key-many-to-one>
    </composite-key>
```

Its produces following error:

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 675; columnNumber: 18; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'composite-key'.
```

I would like to know what is the right way to doing this or any site where explain it.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: I have got it! That was the correct form but I had two errors, I have changed `<composite-key>` by `<composite-id>` and I have removed the id in "class" and it works.

```
<composite-id>
    <key-many-to-one name="role" class="Role" >
        <column name="id_perfil"/>
    </key-many-to-one>
    <key-many-to-one name="secApplication" class="SecApplication">
        <column name="id_aplicacion"/>
    </key-many-to-one>
    <key-many-to-one name="secFunction" class="SecFunction">
        <column name="id_funcion"/>
    </key-many-to-one>
</composite-id>
```